# Simulate eyedropper in actionscript

Tags: actionscript, flash-builder, adobe-illustrator

I'm creating an Illustrator plugin using Actionscript and I wanted that as soon as the mouse leaves the plugin window and is in the illustrator document it would record the mouse positions and get the value of the pixel in these positions using getPixel() but the problem is that I can't get mouse position if the cursor leaves the stage, so is there a solution for this problem or it just can't be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be done. All you can do is listen for [`Event.MOUSE_LEAVE`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#MOUSE_LEAVE), but that isn't going to help you in your situation.